# Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL(updated)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
----extract( month from diff) "month",------(adding this line gives error to the original code) 

select extract( day from diff ) Days, 
       extract( hour from diff ) Hours, 
       extract( minute from diff ) Minutes 
from (
    select (CAST(creation_date as timestamp) - CAST(old_creation_date as timestamp)) diff   
    from [Table Name] 
 );
```

This code is really easy to understand. But could someone please explain how to calculate month as well in here when I try the code, it gives me the following error:

> ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

This Question has already been discussed in this forum (except for Month, it's not my code either, it's originally posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3651607/Andy-korneyev).

Comment: The problem is that `month` is not a standard unit.  If you have an interval that is 61 days, for example, is that 2 months (a 31 day month followed by a 30 day month)?  2 months 1 day (2 30 day months plus a day)?  Or maybe one of the months is 28 or 29 days.  If you can define the algorithm you want, we may be able to help but defining that sort of thing sensibly is hard.

Comment: I am using following code to calculate the month days.                      select to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD') from dual –
 Now,in order to calculate the hire_date of employees in terms of "Employee_hired (duration)= "Xmonths,Xdays,Xhours,Xmin,Xseconds" 
     
Now the above mention code (in my question)already calculates, days,hours,mins,secs. All it is missing is "Months"!!!!!!!!! Looking forward to your response! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `MONTHS_BETWEEN(date1, date2)` to calculate month difference in Oracle.

Comment: I am using following code to calculate the month days.select to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD') from dual

Comment: Now,in order to calculate the hire_date of employees in terms of "Employee_hired (duration)= "Xmonths,Xdays,Xhours,Xmin,Xseconds"

Comment: Now the above mention code (in my question)already calculates, days,hours,mins,secs. All it is missing is "Months"!!!!!!!!! Looking forward to your response! :)